# Seagate NAS Changing Folder Names On Its Own

Tags: network-attached-storage

At one of the sites that I manage, they have a NAS set up for file storage, Seagate brand, ~5 TB. Recently, multiple folders across the NAS have been renaming themselves, with seemingly no pattern or preference.

Random folders are targeted, and the names are roughly similar to: NPRX17~0. The characters and numbers are random, but each folder ends with *"~(some character)"*. I'm at a loss, and the employees of the site cannot always remember what the original names were.

Additionally, sometimes they can change the name back with no trouble, but other times it asks for an administrative password, and not even my  admin credentials will authorize the change.

Any help is appreciated, and I can provide any other information that is needed.

Comment: Are the new names always 8 characters in length? What kind of client OSes use the NAS? Is there any deduplication or compression in play?

Comment: Yes, always 8 characters. The clients are iMacs running Yosemite 10.5. There is a backup server but as far as I know there is no deduplication or compression.

Comment: The 8 character names are a clue. Something, maybe a Windows or other SMB client, might be helpfully "filename mangling" the folders.

Comment: I reconnected everyone's drives with AFP instead of SMB. This seems to have remedied the issue; what would cause this, though?